# Ubuntu installation from live CD: Hangs after splash screen

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, system-installation, windows, 15.04

Ubuntu **12.04.02 i386** live CD *"Try without install"* hangs at splash screen. I looked at output and it hanged after

> `Stopping System V runlevel compatibility      [ok]`

Then i tried **15.04 amd64** live CD and it got stuck again.

I had previously installed **Windows 7 32 bit** and **Ubuntu 12.04** installed on my PC with the ***same configuration***. I now have **Windows 8.1 Pro x64** installed.

Hardware Specifications as follows

Intel DG41RQ Motherboard, Intel Core 2 Duo 2.97 GHz CPU E7500, 2GB x 2 DDR2 RAM, NVIDIA GeForce 8400 GS GPU

Please help. I need a linux OS running not as a virtual OS on my system. I also tried Fedora 21 and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try if it boots with mode "ACPI disabled" or with less resolution in graphics card or simply boot with VESA mode ?

Comment: Worked with "acpi disabled" but took too much time. Thanks @dschinn1001